# Pop over with React best practice

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to implement a pop over that can show on any screen in the web application, using React+Redux+React router

The popover is a container, that is triggered by the application state.

But how is the best practice to do such a thing, since the background is transparent, and it should just show on any screen that is currently presented.

Should it be on top of the router, on hidden, and unhide on present? I can seem to find any example for this senario...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popover can sit inside Root component, something like this.

```
<App>
  <HomePage />
  {shouldShowPopOver && <PopOver />}
</App>
```

You can dispatch `{ type: TOGGLE_POPOVER }` action anywhere, to alter `shouldShowPopOver`. The styling(transparent, whole page etc) should be done through css.

Answer (score 0):

You ca use **react-bootstrap** popover. Checkout the link
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#popovers

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [react-modal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal) component and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [react-modal-dialog](https://github.com/qimingweng/react-modal-dialog) before and it works like a charm! The benefit of this library is that you can define your `<Modal>` component near where the source of trigger is (some button?) and it is easy to trace the condition that determines whether the modal is displayed since it is near the trigger source.

Using this library, technically it does not matter where you put the modal component among your markup as the CSS of the modal makes it appear above all other elements.